# How to reduce the amount of RAM Genymotion uses?

Tags: android, emulation

The android emulator, Genymotion, consumes a lot of RAM. Are there solutions for reducing the amount of RAM it uses?

Comment: How much ram usage are you talking about ? genymotion does say you will need at least 512MB of ram spare

Comment: I own physical 4G ram, swap of 6GB. It's just 10 minutes run a game in android emulator from genymotion then my laptop is almost stopped. When I check, it's nearly swallowed 3.8G physical ram, and about more than 2GB of swap as well. The CPU is ok, it's only about 15% for each (quardcore).

Answer (score 1):

You should reduce the memory from the settings of virtualbox.
1. open virtualbox and select emulator
2. press setting and go to system tab
3. assign the memory to what you want. I just give the emulator 200MB and it works Ok.

Answer (score 1):

you have an application named `runlim` which you can use to run application with  setting certain memory limits.

you can install it with `sudo apt-get install runlim`

how to use it and more information can found at [its man page](http://manned.org/runlim/9a08acfa)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the RAM size and number of cores in the installed devices in Genymotion.

Open Genymotion application
[image: Genymotion application]

Then click the three dots of the device and then you will get a list of options. Then select `edit`. After that, a dialog box will pop and you just have to set a different RAM size (Memory size) in the system section.
[image: Edit RAM]